# Ubuntu 20.04 linux-kvm kernel with nvidia modules?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 20.04, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop workstation which has an nvidia-440 series card in it. It works fine running the standard desktop kernel with the nvidia binary drivers/kernel modules installed.

I want to run KVM VMs on this workstation but when I install all the KVM bits and reboot to the linux-kvm kernel I lose the nvidia drivers. Do I need to compile my own kernel with KVM and the drivers in order to get this to work or am I missing a much easier way?

Note: this is not for KVM GPU passthrough. I want to run KVM VMs on my normal desktop machine with virt-manager and have full graphics/3D acceleration as I do with the normal desktop kernel.

Comment: Why do you need to install linux-kvm kernel? kvm module is not enabled by default into Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: Ah this has helped me debug this further. Not being an Ubuntu user I think I misunderstood what the different kernels are for. The kvm kernel module is included in the desktop version and is loaded but not `kvm_amd` -that one is not loading because the motherboard needed a BIOS update and then virtualisation features could be enabled. Looks like it will work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See response to @ob2's comment which pointed me in the right direction. Anyone having a similar problem should:

- Check that you have the correct kernel modules loaded with `sudo kvm-ok`
- Ensure all virtualisation options are enabled in the motherboard's BIOS (in my case I needed a BIOS update to fix issues before I could enable it)
- Avoid installing the `linux-kvm` kernel as it's not needed to run KVM VMs on a desktop install.

Comment: In regard to "Avoid installing the linux-kvm kernel ... on a desktop install" - to clarify, that is not related to being a "Desktop install", but isn't meant for the KVM Host in general. `linux-kvm` is a reduced kernel to run inside the KVM guest.